# Area of shape made from quarter arcs of circles

Tags: circles

[image]

I have this task. I would first calculate the square that I marked red. That's $6\times 6=36$. Then I add one circle with area $(1.5)^2\times \pi$. So the answer is E, because the area is $36 + 2.25 \times\pi$.

Is that right? I'm a bit confused that answer A to D are far too high.

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange the parts of this shape to see that its area is that of the square plus one complete circle. The answer should be $36+\frac{9\pi}{4}$, so option E is correct.